# Intel XDK - Set Splash Screen

Tags: intel-xdk

I was trying to build an android apk using Intel XDK.I just want to know if there is an option to set the splash screen, icons, application title in some build properties file rather than choosing it everytime you build the apk.

Answer (score 0):

In the current build system the build menu is the only way to specify these assets. However, each time you build your app it will reuse the assets you provided initially. If you create a new project you'll have to provide them again.

In the Cordova build option you provide these assets by specifying them in an intelxdk.config.xml file. This is probably closer to what you are looking for. In the next major release we'll also be providing a way to provide those directly in the XDK, rather than on-line, but only for Cordova build options. However, there will be more flexibility in how you provide those assets, which will be easier to explain once that version of the XDK "hits the streets."

Sorry, but company policy does not allow me to provide a release date. All I can say is that it will be coming in the near future.